# Part of text missing in legend and text boxes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layers, export, pdf

I have had issues lately when exporting to pdf from ArcMap 10.2. Parts of the text sometimes fall off and goes missing. Mostly it's been some lines in legends, but now also text boxes. The text is also missing in legends displayed in Arcmap, but not always.

[image]

This is not how the text in the textbox supposed to look, obviously.

[image]

This screenshot shows a legend, but some of the descriptions are missing.

In Arcmap the legend sometimes looks like this:

[image]

When it's supposed to look like this:

[image]

It happens that this gets solved when exporting a second (or third) time. Which is good, of course, but does not help me in trying to figure out why it's happening in the first place.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there a solution? This is really starting to get on my nerves, and not even creating a new legend helps every time (which is very tideous in the first place).